# Linux directory access control authorised by Openldap

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

Is there any method in openldap I can use to control the ldap accounts access the linux system's dirctories? I have different users which need different authority control in some directories.
  For example two ldap accounts user1 and user2 need access to directories /data and /backup. I want user1 has rwx power in /data and rx in /backup, meanwhile user2 has rx in /data but rwx in /backup. How can I do in openldap to achieve this target? Thanks very much.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-acls-setting.html

Comment: I know this is an acl control method on linux system level, are there some ways to save this acl rule in an openldap account on openldap software level?